# Friendly Urls in expression engine

Tags: expressionengine

Any help would be appreciated.  I understand you can use 
    `{path=about/organization}` when creating links to pages because they are in groups.  But there isn't a way to nest groups I'm sure there is an way to accomplish the objective

**Objective:**

```
 website.com/about/organization
 website.com/about/organization/executives
 website.com/about/organization/page3
```

**Directory structure:**

about

---organization

---executives

---page3

**Question**

How do I create a `{path=about/organization/executives}` that loads about/organization/executives in the directory structure so the URL is website.com/about/organization/executives ?

Any sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As @AllInOne suggested, Structure would be your best and easiest approach here, but when learning EE, it's best to understand the templates and template groups before approaching additional add-ons. Also don't think of template groups as being folders and URL structuring, I wrote a similar answer [here on the EE StackExchange](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14121/how-do-i-choose-a-different-design-template/14124#14124).

But consider groups as ways of grouping pages or design templates, not relevant to the URL. Although it would be clunky, you could replicate your URL requirements all in a single primary index template - although this wouldn't be recommended.

I never use the {path...} tags, instead I just utilise the URL directly e.g. `href="/about/organization"` - you don't have to use {path...} at all. This will then allow you to use `href="/about/organization/executives"`. The important thing to understand is that the first segment (about) will always be the template group, unless your primary template group index is catching the URL (so you don't actually need an "about" template group!). You can have a URL as deep as you like, but the first segment will normally always dictate the group used and the 2nd segment will dictate the template, you can then use this template to manage deeper links, or if the template doesn't match, it will use the index template.

Note that if you have strict 404 settings, it may conflict with the template matching - always a bit of trial and error :P

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking at 3 layers you basically can work with what EE gives you out of the box.

The url structure is as follows:

template_group/template/url_title

So in your example you'd have a channel with an entry with a url_title of 'executives' and another with the url_title of 'page3'.

Your template_group would be about and your template would be organization.

If you need something  more complex take a look at the [Structure](http://buildwithstructure.com/) add on.

It does all this and more...

If you need more advice on this or other EE matters I'd recommend asking at https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/